# Play framework 1.2.4 migration? what to do best?

Tags: authentication, playframework, migration, authorization

I want to add authorization & authentication to my app, it's using play 1.2.4, what is better, migrate whole app to 2.0 now or use some modules for 1.2.4 and fight later with migration and reimplemeting authentication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to implement authentication and authorization, then migrating to Play 2.0 is certainly not required. Besides, migration from 1.x to 2.0 is not that easy, depending on the complexity of your application. There are some quite significant differences between the two major versions of the framework. Reimplementing authentication later will not be the biggest of your worries should you embark on a migration mission.

For Play 1.2.4 authorization, I can recommend the [Deadbolt module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/deadbolt), it is very flexible yet easy to start working with. For authentication, the basic secure module can be extended to cover most needs.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently had to roll out auth for a Play 1.2.4 site and it was fairly painless using  [Play-ScalaSecure](https://github.com/asinghal/Play-ScalaSecure). Might not be that helpful if you not using Scala. . .

The downside is the docs are pretty sparse, but setting up was easy and implementation is simple. Just apply the *Secure* trait to controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I have evaulated migration of my 1.2.4 application, which is currently in development and is soon to be released for the first time, to version 2.0 just yesterday and it was not a hard decision to stay with 1.2.4 version. Playframework 2.0 is a VERY different framwork than 1.2.4, at least from my point of view:

- Controllers are different
- Persistance access layer is different
- Templating is different
- Configuration is different
- etc.

No doubt that my next application will go with Playframework 2.0, but my current target is to do the release for my current application as soon as possible. Migration to 2.0 would slow this target considerably. If you have the same target, then I recommend you to stay with 1.2.4 and use  [Deadbolt Module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/deadbolt) as mentioned here already. What I would do, is to quickly learn how things are done in Playframework 2.0 and design new things in your current 1.2.4 application in a way which would make it easy to migrate...